# ImageJ plugin DHM Utilities

Tags: plugins, imagej

I wanted to install phase unwrapping plugin which is one of the collection DHM Utilities.
I don't mind install all the collection DHM Utilities.

The link to the collection: [text](DHM Utilities).

I'll be very grateful for showing me working method how to install collection of plugins DHM Utilities.

I read instruction on GitHub, here is the link: [text](https://github.com/sudgy/phase-unwrapping) and I understand that I have to only add URL link, but I don't know how. I use ImageJ 1.54h on macOS.

Comment: The descriptions appears being for Fiji, not plain ImageJ. I'm not sure if the plugin will work with plain ImageJ and I'm far from sure if this Forum here is the right place to get help. Here we are mainly dealing with _coding_ macros and plugins for ImageJ.